# When duplicating my event the event description is not copying over

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tinymce, rich-text-editor

In my schema I have:
`t.string "description"`

In my model I have:
`has_rich_text :description`

In my suggest event form I have:

```
<%= f.text_area :description, placeholder: 'Enter the description of the event here', label: "Tell us about the event.", :class => "tinymce" %>
```

In my duplicate method in the controller I have:

```
def duplicate
      original_event = Event.friendly.find(params[:id])
      @event = original_event.dup
      @event.name = original_event.name += " (copy)"
      @event.slug = original_event.slug
      @event.description = original_event.description
      @event.address = original_event.address
      @event.event_frequency = original_event.event_frequency
      @event.event_types = original_event.event_types
      @event.event_start_date = original_event.event_start_date
      @event.event_end_date = original_event.event_end_date
      @event.dance_styles = original_event.dance_styles
      @event.website_url = original_event.website_url
      @event.facebook_url = original_event.facebook_url
      @event.instagram_url = original_event.instagram_url
      @event.ticket_url = original_event.ticket_url
      @event.artists = original_event.artists

      render "suggest_event"
    end
```

I have also tried different variations with no luck:

```
@event.description.body = original_event.description.dup
@event.description_rich_text = original_event.description_rich_text.dup
@event.description = original_event.description.to_s
```

In my rails console when I display the event description I get the following:

```
3.0.2 :004 > e.description
  ActionText::RichText Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "action_text_rich_texts".* FROM "action_text_rich_texts" WHERE "action_text_rich_texts"."record_id" = $1 AND "action_text_rich_texts"."record_type" = $2 AND "action_text_rich_texts"."name" = $3 LIMIT $4  [["record_id", 21], ["record_type", "Event"], ["name", "description"], ["LIMIT", 1]]                                                          
  Rendered /Users/ogarocious/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.2/gems/actiontext-7.0.4/app/views/action_text/contents/_content.html.erb within layouts/action_text/contents/_content (Duration: 5.5ms | Allocations: 2229)                           
 =>                                                                   
#<ActionText::RichText:0x00007fa41c340a68                             
 id: 28,                                                              
 name: "description",                                                 
 body: #<ActionText::Content "<div class=\"trix-conte...">,           
 record_type: "Event",                                                
 record_id: 21,                                                       
 created_at: Mon, 20 Feb 2023 02:27:52.500765000 UTC +00:00,
 updated_at: Tue, 21 Feb 2023 19:49:38.187025000 UTC +00:00>
```

When I inspect the description element I get:

```
<body id="tinymce" class="mce-content-body vsc-initialized" data-id="event_description" aria-label="Rich Text Area. Press ALT-0 for help." contenteditable="true" spellcheck="false" data-new-gr-c-s-check-loaded="14.1097.0" data-gr-ext-installed=""><div class="trix-content"><div class="trix-content">Awesome Fusion Event in Medellin</div></div></body>
```

Is there something missing with the event description/rich text/action text/trix content that needs to be pointed to?

I am also using the TinyMCE editor for rich text formatting that displaying the text which has been working fine for creating editing and displaying the description, just ran into this snag with the event duplication, everything else is duplicating over just fine.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was removing the column for description from my events table as the description was also being used for the ActionText rich text table connected to the events table.

Once I did this I was able to successfully duplicate the description with
`event.description = original_event.description.body.dup` in the duplicate method in my events controller.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried `.dup` ?
Maybe it can helps